# What does this Ruby code means?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

The command

```
rails generate scaffold Post name:string title:string content:text
```

generated the following `20101109001203_create_posts.rb` file:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :title
      t.text :content

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :posts
  end
end
```

Since I'm new to Ruby (just read [one book](http://www.humblelittlerubybook.com/)), I have some questions on this block of code:

1. What does `self.` means in `self.up` and `self.down` ? How it differs from simply `up` and `down` ?
2. What does all these colons (`:`) means in `:posts`, `:name`, etc. ? Is that just a part of the variable name ?
3. What does `t.string :name` means ? Is that a call to `string` function on object `t` with parameter `:name` ?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you define a method using `def foo`, you're creating an instance method called `foo`. I.e. if you have an instance of class `CreatePosts` you can do `the_instance.foo`. However by doing `def self.foo` (or alternatively `def CreatePosts.foo` which does the same thing, because `self == CreatePosts` in the `class ... end`-block), you're defining a singleton method which is only available on `CreatePosts` itself. I.e. it is called as `CreatePosts.foo` not `the_instance.foo` (this is somewhat similar to static methods in other languages, but not quite because you can use the same syntax to define singleton methods on objects that aren't classes).
2. `:name` has nothing to do with any variable called `name`. It's a symbol literal, which is kind of like an interned immutable string (though the Symbol class does not define any methods for string-manipulation). You can think of symbols as some sort of mini-strings which are used when you just need to label something and don't need to do string manipulation.
3. Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 1,3 - Understood. Regarding 2: Is that some kind of "goto" label ? Where the code that is defined under these labels located ? Is that true that these labels must start with a colon ? Could you point me to some Ruby tutorial on this topic ? Thanks again!!

Comment: @Misha: No, nothing like that. As I said, they're like bare-bones strings. And yes, they need to start with a colon.

Comment: OK, I think I got it. `:name` is just like the string `"name"` but without any string functionality. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

1. `self` is the migration file and `up` and `down` apply and reverse the migration respectively.
2. The colons are symbols and denote names, type, scale, etc.. and they denote by column type/order
3. `t.sting :name` means create a column on the current migration object with name `name` and type `string`

Comment: `self` is not a file. `self` is the class `CreatePosts`.

Answer (score 1):

1. def self.up defines the class method up.  When rails runs that migration it will call CreatePosts.up.  The alternative being def up which would define an instance method which could be called with CreatePosts.new.up.
2. :name (for example) is an example of a Symbol.  As symbol is similar to a string, but stripped down to the point where there's almost nothing there but the text.  In this case they're just using it to tell the #string method what you want the column to be called.
3. You got that exactly right.

You may find this helpful.

http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.0/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#M000666

Comment: Ooops, it looks like he updated his docs to 3.0.1.

This one works as of right now. :)
http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.1/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#M000666